# Ioctl() innapropriate for this device java/linux

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to sign a file with a gpg key using java.
I performed the command through the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` from java and I get a weird output.

```
Process p;
String key = comboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
String password = new String(passwordField1.getPassword());
String cmd = String.format("gpg -u %s --passphrase %s --output %s.sig --sign %s",
                           key, password, pathfile, pathfile);
try {
   p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

   BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                            InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

   BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                            InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
   String s = null;
   String s1 = null;
   s = stdInput.readLine();
   System.out.println(s);
   s1 = stdError.readLine();
   System.out.println(s1);
```

Anyone got and idea on why I got this output?

Comment: `Anyone got and idea on why I got this output?` - what output exactly are you getting? And where does it occur (which line in the code is executed when that output appears)?

Comment: Sorry though I linked the error: gpg: failed signature : Ioctl()  for this device

Comment: Have you tried the same `gpg` command from the command line? Does it work there? (put a `System.err.println(cmd)` before your `exec()` call and try exactly the same command on the command line)

Comment: Try on command line and work perfectly